# I wish to cancel a bounty

Tags: support, bounties, account-suspension

It was recommended in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279144/should-users-suspended-from-a-community-be-allowed-to-award-a-bounty-previously that I should log a support request to have the appropriate [bounty](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121037/is-has-or-will-read-grammatical) removed and possibly refunded so it can be reawarded.

If this is the appropriate course of action could someone help me do this, since I cannot currently post to or interact with the community in question.

Comment: Is this bounty on Meta SE? If not, you might have better luck asking on the community's specific meta site.

Comment: If you can still flag, you should custom flag the question you posted a bounty on, explaining clearly your problem and that you would like it to be cancelled. A moderator will review the flag and act on it. If you can't flag, use the contact us link at the bottom of every page and do the same, linking to the question. Also, what @scriptHero said.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to post in Meta English Language and Usage, or to flag posts on the main EL&L site at the moment :/. Will check see if the contact us link is there...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter http://english.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: I found it. Thank you :).

Comment: Nobody actually told you to request that the bounty be refunded in your linked post, nor should a mod do so if requested, given that the bounty has been there for a while and attracted attention.

Comment: Yes they did, Servy: "If anything, I would support request to cancel any active bounties when an account is being suspended. (with or without refund.)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are suspended, you can't ask on the site meta for a moderator to take some action. You can't flag either since that needs 15 reputation and you have one while suspended.

The best option you have it to contact the team by clicking on *Contact Us* in the footer on the site it concerns. You will usually receive a message back in a few days (so don't expect an immediate response, they usually have a backlog).

Your request can be denied, first because a bounty is just 'advertisement money', which you now have fully used. The question also received two new answers, which are eligible to receive at least half the bounty, so it would be unfair to deny that.

Comment: You need 15 rep to flag and while suspended you have 1, so no you can't flag anything.

Comment: Makes sense. I have been searching for that half an hour but actually it is quite simple. Thanks @rob